# Django production static files are not working (deployment)

Tags: django, python-3.x

When deploying my Django project in the Linux server, the static files are not getting uploaded. I have followed instructions on the Docs but it doesn't seem to work.

**This is what I had done so far:**

**settings.py:**

```
DEBUG = False

.....

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')  

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

**urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    #remaining urls here....
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**For deploying static files, I typed this command:**

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

All the files are being pushed to a directory called 'staticfiles' in the root folder and the command works as expected.

However, when starting the Django server, all the static files i.e JS, CSS and media files are not seen. In fact, the site is broken. But when the Debug mode is **set to True**, then the site works well again.

What went wrong? Can anyone let me know where I am making a mistake?

Comment: can you check the console what error it printing ?

Comment: One of the errors I am getting is this: GET **http://my_server_address/static/myapp/js/func.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)**

Comment: Did you set up your web server to serve the static files? As is clear from your URLs, "static" is only for development.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes, the web server is set up. I am using Apache.

Comment: Set up *how*? Show the configuration.

Comment: @DanielRoseman You're right. I am extremely sorry. How can I implement the configuration process?

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you have set up Apache and your site is being served by it, you have a configuration file; post it.

Comment: I have served my files in the server but I haven't set up Apache. My question now is how can I go about the configuration process? What should I include in the configuration file?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

Answer (score 0):

**FOR PRODUCTION**

Install the following packages

```
yum install python-pip httpd mod_wsgi
```

Configure a Python Virtual Environment and Django Project

Configure Apache

```
vim /etc/httpd/conf.d/django.conf


Alias /static /home/user/myproject/static
<Directory /home/user/myproject/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/user/myproject/myproject>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-path=/home/user/myproject:/home/user/myproject/myprojectenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup myproject
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py
```

Give permission to Apache service to access the files. and restart the server

**FOR DEVELOPMENT**

In urls.py add the following

```
from django.views.static import serve
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
    url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
]
```

In settings.py please add this

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Comment: What does 'serve' do here?

Comment: that kinda a wrong way of using static file, it's better to use `{% static %}` tag then define the path url

Comment: @LinhNguyen can you show a small demonstration, please?

Comment: demonstration ? did you follow django [docs about staticfile](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/) it should be all there, you see that you can use `src="{% static "my_app/example.jpg" %}"` to get the path to the files

Comment: please refer to my comment above of check the console error

Comment: also add this to your settings STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

Comment: @danny_boy i have edited it use this in your settings.py file

Comment: This is the wrong answer. Please do not continue to mention this. `serve` is only for development. And OP was correct that STATIC_ROOT should be "staticfiles", not "static".

Comment: @SachinSingh you may want to read the doc on how to serve static files ON PRODUCTION, this would avoid you the pain of posting the worst possible advice.

Comment: Okk i have updated my answer for both production and development